# Rails - ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I'm trying to receive an SMS from the twilio API. I generated a separate reply controller that doesn't deal with anything else in my routes or resources. It uses a post method to communicate with twilio. Im getting the error:

```
"ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):"
```

replycontroller.rb

```
class ReplyController < ApplicationController

  require 'twilio-ruby'

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def hart1

    twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Message 'The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!'
    end

    content_type 'text/xml'
    twiml.text
  end

end
```

here are my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  resources :phones
  resources :users
  root 'home#index'

  post "/reply/hart1" => "reply#hart1"

end
```

I'm under the impression I'm routing this improperly. The Heroku console also gives me a 500 error so I know it's something fixable on my end.

Comment: I'm not very sure, but as per [THIS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms/hello-monkey) docs, you may try `r.message(body: "The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!")`

Comment: Also, I feel `r.Message` should be `r.message`(smaller case) [REF](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-receive-and-reply-in-ruby)

Comment: Which version of the Ruby library are you using?

Comment: @philnash ruby 2.3.0p0 & Rails 4.2.4

Comment: Sorry, the Twilio gem version :)

Answer (score 0):

To send a message with 'twillio-ruby' your code should look like this

```
# put your own credentials here
account_sid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
auth_token = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'

# set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

# Send SMS message
@client.api.account.messages.create(
  from: '+FROMNUMBER',
  to: '+TONUMBER',
  body: 'The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!'
)
```

in you controller it would look like

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
class ReplyController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def hart1
    send_text_message
    content_type 'text/xml'
  end

  private

  def send_text_message
    # put your own credentials here
    account_sid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    auth_token = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'

    # set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

    # Send SMS message
    @client.api.account.messages.create(
     from: '+FROMNUMBER',
     to: '+TONUMBER',
     body: 'The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!'
    )
  end
end
```

The documentation for 'twillo-ruby' is here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby

Comment: He's trying to [reply to an incoming message, which you can do with TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request).

Answer (score 0):

I wound up going the route nzajt mentioned where you send a regular text rather than the reply Twilio mentions. The routing was fine. Everything hit the post route on my server from twilio and I was able to take all the params I wanted from its payload for use. Thanks guys.